# How do I select the first effective date if there are few records with same details?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view

**UPDATED**

Below is the scenario:

> EMP| Effective_dt | Position | Worklocation |
>   01 | 01/01/2019   |  IT SUP  |     BRANCH   |
>   01 | 01/06/2019   |  IT SUP  |     HQ       |
>   01 | 01/07/2019   | SENIOR IT|     HQ       |
>   01 | 12/08/2019   | SENIOR IT|     BRANCH   |
>   01 | 15/11/2020   |  MGR IT  |     BRANCH   |
>   02 | 01/02/2019   |ACCOUNTANT|     HQ       |

I wanted to create a view table to show the latest work location and the effective date of the employees.

Expected result:

> ID | Effective_dt | Worklocation |
>   01 | 12/08/2019   |     BRANCH   |
>   02 | 01/02/2019   |     HQ       |

I wanted to create a view table to get the latest work location and the latest effective date from the change of work location.

I am not familiar on how to search for this condition. Please kindly guide me on this or tell me any keyword for this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using `row_number()`

```
select t1.id, t1.Effective_dt, t1.WorkLocation from 
    (select EMP as id
        , row_number() over (partition by EMP order by Effective_dt desc) as rn
        , WorkLocation 
        , Effective_dt
     from table
     where Effective_dt <= getdate())t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: hi, I have updated my question. the query that you have provided is similar to what I wanted to archive. But the effective date has to be the latest effective date from the change of work location. Thanks

Comment: I added `where Effective_dt <= getdate()`, so you can only view their latest position

Comment: Based on my scenario and expected result above, i wanted to get 12/08/2019 as the  effective date instead of the latest date (15/11/2020) and the work of location is BRANCH.

Comment: what's the datatype of your Effective_dt?

Comment: the effective_dt is using datetime

Comment: yes i have tried. but i got the latest date (15/11/2020) instead of 12/08/2019.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the Scenario, 
Your Expected Output will wrong. 
because you notice that **01 | 01/07/2019 | SENIOR IT| HQ |** greatest date will there.
anyway i just try as sample and I wish to share with you..

So your expected output will becomes :

ID | Effective_dt | Worklocation |
01 | 01/07/2019   | HQ |
02 | 01/02/2019   | HQ |

```
DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE 
(
    EMP INT,
    EFFECTIVE_DT DATE,
    POSITION  VARCHAR(20),
    WORKLOCATION  VARCHAR(50) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @TEMP (EMP,EFFECTIVE_DT,POSITION,WORKLOCATION)VALUES
(01 ,'01/01/2019','IT SUP','BRANCH'),
(01 ,'01/06/2019','IT SUP','HQ'),
(01 ,'01/07/2019','IT SUP','HQ'),
(02 ,'01/02/2019','IT SUP','HQ');


SELECT 
DISTINCT(EMP),
MAX(EFFECTIVE_DT) AS EFFECTIVE_DT
INTO #TEMP
FROM @TEMP
GROUP BY EMP

SELECT 
TMP.EMP,
TMP.EFFECTIVE_DT AS Effective_dt,
WORKLOCATION AS Worklocation
FROM #TEMP TMP
INNER JOIN @TEMP TMP1 ON TMP1.EMP = TMP.EMP AND TMP1.EFFECTIVE_DT = TMP.EFFECTIVE_DT 
ORDER BY TMP.Effective_dt DESC
```

I hope this will helps you..